# Need help on NoClassDefFound error

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

I'm working on a service to prepare spreadsheet for a report. I'm using `jxl-2.4.2.jar` to achieve this ( please note that I can't use the latest version due to compatibility constraints). When I execute the code locally on my eclipse it works fine. My eclipse has java 1.5.

When I deploy my code in my test environment, its giving `NoClassdefFound error` for `jxl.*` ( any classes in jxl ). My test environment has IBM's java 1.5. I believe it doesn't make any difference if I use IBM's version or Sun's version of java in this context.

I believe this error could happen when JVM fails to load the class at runtime or if the class has any static methods/properties. I checked the classes and none of them have static contents. So, this could be something else.

FYI.. I'm using ant to build the project & I check the build.xml. It is showing the correct version of java 1.5. Could someone please help to fix this error? Also Just FYI.. my project resides on AIX 5.0 server.

Any help in this regard *much appreciated*. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you build with `ant` you should end up, in the `dist` directory, with your `jar` file and also a `lib` file. Did you move both of these to your test environment? The `lib` folder needs to be next to the `jar` or you need to use the `-cp` option when running the `jar`.

Comment: Hover over the "noclassdeffounderror" tag and read it.  USUALLY it's due to a mismatch of jar files, either compiling with one set and running with a different set, or having two incompatible jars in the class path.  But it can be due to coding errors in the class itself (wrong package name, eg), errors during static init, et al.

Comment: @hotlicks apparently that is not the right place for the explanation.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - What isn't the right place for what explanation?

Comment: @HotLicks in the hover text for a tag.

Comment: Print too small or what?

Answer (score 0):

This error implies that your dependency is missing at runtime i.e. the set of dependent jars is not not correct.
`jxl-2.4.2.jar` is not getting shipped along with deployment, so just to resolve the issue , you can manually copy this jar in dependent lib folder of deployment.

But proper fix will be to get your ANT build checked.

Comment: Class path problems are probably the hardest beginners experience.  It is only self explanatory when you have seen it many times yourself

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Agree, i have changed the working of my answer.

Comment: The error SUGGESTS that there may be a missing dependency.  There are many different possible reasons for that exception, though.